# Linker error with gdk_pixbuf_xlib_get_from_drawable

Tags: c, gtk, gtk2, gdk

If I attempt to use the function `gdk_pixbuf_xlib_get_from_drawable`, it results in the following linker error:

```
undefined reference to gdk_pixbuf_xlib_get_from_drawable
```

I am compiling it using the `gtk+-2.0` and `libwnck-1.0` pkg-config options, like this:

```
... `pkg-config gtk+-2.0 libwnck-1.0 --cflags --libs`
```

I have also tried adding `gdk-2.0` and `x11` to the pkg-config options, but it still did not work.

My code looks roughly like this:

```
wnck_window_get_geometry (window, &xp, &yp, &widthp, &heightp);
pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_xlib_get_from_drawable (pixbuf, gdk_window,
    NULL, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, widthp, heightp);
```

Comment: what are you #including for the definition of that function?

Comment: @jku At first, I just included `gtk.h` and `libwnck.h`. Then, I tried adding `gdk/gdk.h`, `gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h`, and `X11/Xlib.h` separately in turn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add gdk-pixbuf-xlib-2.0 to your pkg-config checks, and include gdk-pixbuf-xlib.h.

Comment: This has solved my linker error, but when I run the program, it causes a segmentation fault. I have tried passing an XID instead of a GdkWindow, but it still segfaults.

Comment: You asked about the link error and that's resolved.  Without stack traces, more code, and so on it's impossible to help more.